# how do I properly align my tkinter buttons with spaces

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I want it to look like this:

[image]

so I did this:

```
seats = ['F11', 'F12', 'F13', 'F14', 'F21', 'F22', 'F23', 'F24', 'B31', 'B32', 'B33', 'B34',
     'B41', 'B42', 'B43', 'B44', 'B51', 'B52', 'B53', 'B54', 'E61', 'E62', 'E63', 'E64', 
     'E71', 'E72', 'E73', 'E74', 'E81', 'E82', 'E83', 'E84', 'E91', 'E92', 'E93', 'E94']

for i in seats:
if i[2] == "3" or i[2] == "4":
    Label(root, text="").grid(row=int(i[1]),column=3, columnspan=12)
    Button(root, text=i).grid(row=int(i[1]), column=int(i[2])+10)
else:
    Button(root, text=i).grid(row=int(i[1]), column=int(i[2]))
```

which gives me this:

[image]

Im missing the horizontal blanks, is there a way to incoperate it?

Comment: Is your attempt for the *blankets* an empty label?

Comment: use a frame and set its `padx` and `pady` to some value, then pack the corresponding widgets in that frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create six frames, one for each group of buttons. You can then use `grid` to position those six frames with as much padding between each group as you like. Then, within each frame you can place the buttons however you want.

Another option is to simply add a blank row between each group. You can leave the row empty but give it a minimum size with `rowconfigure`, or you can place a frame in it that is the same height as the amount of empty space that you want.

Comment: I tired to add the buttons within the frames itself but instead it places the buttons in the mainframe even after specifying where its placed.

Comment: the parent frame isnt considered and instead the grid is